# Find $u, v$ such that $F\left[x, \frac{1}{x+y}, \frac{1}{y} \right]$ is integral over $F[u, v]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field and let $R= F\left[x, \frac{1}{x+y}, \frac{1}{y} \right]$. Find $u, v \in R$ such that $R$ is integral over $F[u,v]$.

Let $y'=\frac{1}{y}$. I considered the polynomial $f$
$$f(t)=(t-x)(t-y')\left( t-\frac{x}{xy'+1}\right)\left( t-\frac{y'}{xy'+1}\right).$$
I couldn't think of $u, v$ such that the coefficients of $f$ (checked it using wolfram) are in $F[u,v]$. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field, and let $R=F[a,b,c]$ where
$$
\begin{cases}
a=x\\[4pt]
b={\large{\frac{1}{x+y}}}\\[4pt]
c={\large{\frac{1}{y}}}\\
\end{cases}
\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
$$
and let $u,v,w\in R$ be given by
$$
\begin{cases}
u=a+b+c\\[4pt]
v=ab+bc+ca\\[4pt]
w=abc\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $a,b,c$ satisfy the equation $p(t)=0$, where
$$p(t)=t^3-ut^2+vt-w$$
hence $a,b,c$ are ntegral over $F[u,v,w]$.

But identically, for $a,b,c$ defined as above, we have
$$
w^6
+(6v-2u^2)w^4
+(u^4+9v^2-6u^2v+27)w^2
+(4u^3-18uv)w
+(4v^3-u^2v^2)
=
0
$$
hence $w$ is integral over $F[u,v]$.

It follows that $R$ is integral over $F[u,v]$.

Comment: oh, we can do it for arbitrary three variables $a, b, c$ in general. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andrew: No, not arbitrary. It's not automatic that $abc$ is integral over $F[a+b+c,ab+bc+ca]$, but for the given $a,b,c$, it is.